# bundle doesn't know what ruby is?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

So, not too long ago, this command worked on my computer, however, I don't remember if I changed something, but now after removing all my Ruby installs, and just having ChefDK 0.4.0 installed and in my path with the .chefdk/gem, and C:\opscode\chefdk\bin;C:\opscode\chefdk\embedded\bin in my path, I get the following result.

```
C:\Users\Phillip\Desktop\password_vault
λ bundle exec ruby bin\password_vault
bundler: command not found: ruby
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`

C:\Users\Phillip\Desktop\password_vault
λ bundle install
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.4.2
Using bundler 1.8.5
Using rack 1.6.0
Using rack-protection 1.5.3
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sinatra 1.4.5
Using password_vault 0.0.1 from source at .
Bundle complete! 3 Gemfile dependencies, 7 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

C:\Users\Phillip\Desktop\password_vault
λ bundle exec ruby bin\password_vault
bundler: command not found: ruby
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`

C:\Users\Phillip\Desktop\password_vault
```

I'm not sure what all else I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Ruby installed, because bundler is using it.

Somehow your bundle path doesn't have Ruby, or has lost track of it.

To solve this, use `bundle --path`, such as:

```
bundle --path "C:\foo\goo\hoo\ruby\bin"
```

The path is wherever you put Ruby on your system, plus any other path items that you want be available to bundler, such as `bin` directories of other software.

Bundler will remember the path for future installs on this machine.